# I want to get a list item position from an adapter when I touch a list item

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to get list item position from adapter when i touch on a list item. please suggest how can we do this.
i was trying to get as follow:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            int adapterIndex = listView.pointToPosition((int) motionEvent.getX(),(int) motionEvent.getY());
            int firstViewItemIndex = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int viewIndex = adapterIndex - firstViewItemIndex;
            pos = listView.pointToPosition((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
            pos=pos-listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        }
}
```

but always got 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
MyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long l) {

            //action for position, for example one toast and show value of var "position"

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try below approch:

set list items positions in adapter views by setTag() and from onTouch method you can get item position by  view.getTag() method.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.getPositionForView(View view)` is your method. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { ..` method of the Adapter Class the `position` is the current touched list item's position.